# Append to 2-dimensional array

Tags: java

should be a easy one but I want to add say "one","one,"one" or "two","two,"two" to an a 2-dimensional array based on a condition

```
 String[][] headings = new String[][] { {
        "three",
        "three",
        "three"
               } };
```

Comment: Add them how? You are not even specifying the dimensions of your array.

Comment: The array you are declaring here is fixed size (1 x 3), based on your initial values. It will not automatically redemension itself to add new elements.

Comment: My bad...I see what you mean ...guess I cant do it the way I was thinking

Comment: what If I dont declare the size?

Comment: You are not declaring them anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this exactly task you can do next. Note you can't dynamically resize arrays, so you should care about size at start or use lists.

```
    String[][] headings = new String[][] { {
    "three",
    "three",
    "three"
           }, {} }; // note placeholder for to-be-added triplet.
     String val = condition ? "one": "two";
     headings[1] = new String[] {val, val, val};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont want them to go in the next element.  I want go right after the last "three",

Comment: @Doc Holiday: Then why do you need a two dimensional array?

Comment: like this? `String[][] headings = new String[][] { { "three",    "three",    "three", val, val, val }};`

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand how you want to dimension your array. If after the add you are going to have 6 elements they will be placed how? 1 x 6? 2 x 3? Anyway, you can instead use an `ArrayList<String[]>`:

```
ArrayList<String[]> headings = new ArrayList<String[]>();
headings.add(new String[] { "three", "three", "three" });

if(/* condition */)
    headings.add(new String[] { "two", "two", "two" });
else
    headings.add(new String[] { "one", "one", "one" });
```